# Ajax div update to insert JS for subsequent asynchronous request to external site

Tags: forms, ajax

I wanted to use the postscribe library (https://github.com/krux/postscribe) to make an asynchronous request to google trends, which would update a div with a graph without requiring a page reload.

Using the library on its own through a few methods (drupal_add_js or a custom block) works just fine, but I wish for the js code to be reloaded everytime the appropriate ajax callback is initiated.

```
$form['trends-visual'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="trends-ajax-wrap">',
  '#suffix' => '<div id="trends-visualization-container"></div></div>',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
);

$form['trends-graph'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="trends-graph",',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'trends_ajax_submit_callback',
  )
);
```

The callback

```
function trends_ajax_submit_callback($ajax, &$form, &$form_state)  {

 $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 $commands = array();
 $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#trends-visualization-container',
   '<script>
     (function ($) {
       Drupal.behaviors.trends_ajax = {
         attach: function (context, settings) {
            postscribe(\'#trends-graph\', 
            \'<script src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=Stephen%20Harper&tz=Etc/GMT%2B4&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330">
            </script>\');
         }
       }
      })(jQuery);</script>');

return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Triggering the Ajax with $form['submit'] results in the following JS error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

This is referencing my JS code, specifically this line:

```
postscribe('#trends-graph', '<script src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=Stephen%20Harper&tz=Etc/GMT%2B4&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330">
```

Through googling it is suggested that there is an illegal hidden character somewhere, but after having looked at the code in VIM, EMACS, KATE, OKTETA, ATOM, JSBin, JSFiddle, and CodePen I am unable to find any strange hidden characters. The closest anomaly I can find are 0A characters through the hexeditor (Okteta), but I don't think those should be causing any problems.

Could someone provide some info as to how I can continue to troubleshoot?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by escaping one more character and removing one semicolon.

In the 2nd argument of ajax_command_html I was attaching a string which had two script tags, one inner and one outter. The inner closing script tag wasn't being passed unless I escaped its forward slash, like this:

```
<\/script>
```

Lastly, I had to remove the semicolon that was following "(jQuery)", just prior to closing the outter script tag, like this:

```
})(jQuery)</script>');
```

Hopefully this can be of use to someone!